# Visual Studio Code color theme in Visual Studio 2017 for JavaScript and TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

As the topic suggests I would like to import/set Visual Studio Code color theme in Visual Studio 2017 for JavaScript and TypeScript files. The files I therefore would like to set color theme for are: `.js, .jsx, .ts and .tsx`. If it is not possible to edit per file or language then I would like to know if it is possible to import a whole theme that looks like Visual Studio Code.

In short I would like this:

[image]

To look like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you have any success in the last 2 years? I need this so much

Answer (score 2):

I did end up finding a way!

**TL:DR**:

Download [JavaScript.tmLanguage](https://gist.github.com/riddheshMarkandeya/e4745ffcb0c7a028d576ccaaa96ec945#file-javascript-tmlanguage) and [JavaScript.tmTheme](https://gist.github.com/riddheshMarkandeya/e4745ffcb0c7a028d576ccaaa96ec945#file-javascript-tmtheme).

- Go to %USERPROFILE%\.vs\Extensions\javascript\Syntaxes (%USERPROFILE% usually is C:\Users\{username})
- Create the folders if they are not present.
- Paste the two files
- Restart the VS, should have the vscode highlighting for js, jsx etc files!

---

If you want to port any vscode theme to Visual Studio,

- In vscode generate color theme from current setting.([Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991223/5773530)) This will be the tmTheme file
- Get tmLanguage of the language from vscode's [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d5e12a12ddcdbffa565ea36aec17d94df7c9f3d9/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScript.tmLanguage.json)
- Convert both json to plist. (I used [plist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plist))
- Add [filetypes](https://gist.github.com/riddheshMarkandeya/e4745ffcb0c7a028d576ccaaa96ec945#file-javascript-tmlanguage-L15-L32) to tmLanguage file if its not there.
- Add both to %USERPROFILE%\.vs\Extensions\language\Syntaxes folder.
- Done!

I have tested for VS2019, and as I followed [VS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2019#add-support-for-non-supported-languages), it seems like it should work till VS2015.

Screenshot:
[image: Sample react syntax highlighting in VS]

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that other TSLS features are working correctly on your installation? (formatting, completions, etc).

There is a known issue with TextMate support in VS where sometimes there are missing colors. To make sure this isn’t the case here can you try running the following from a VS Developer cmd prompt to see if it resolves the issue:
• devenv.exe /updateconfiguration
• devenv.exe /setup

What is your VS installation directory?
Ex: C:\Program Files[ (x86)]\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE

Does the tmLanguage folder exist under the TypeScript installation path?
Ex: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\tmLanguage

Do you have any custom grammar files (.tmLanguage, .tmTheme) located in your user profile?
Ex: %userprofile%.vs\Extensions

Can you verify this isn’t a TM language caching issue:

- Close VS
- Go to the TexMateCache location:
  %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio[15.0XXXXX]\TextMateCache
- Delete all the .cache files in this directory
- Reopen VS and try to repro

Does this resolve the issue? Do you have the TypeScript TextMate
   registry key set correctly?

- Close VS
- Open regedit
- Select HKLM
- File > Load Hive …
- Open
  %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx\privateregistry.bin
  (you can name the hive VS)
- Now navigate to:
  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\VS\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15[XXXXX]_Config\TextMate\Repositories

Comment: This is not an error with Visual Studio, it's just that Visual Studio's colour theme uses different (in this case undesirable) colours. They're asking someone to make a Dark+ theme (default in Visual Studio Code) for Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You can confirm this by going to Visual Studio Code, `File -> Preferences -> Color Theme` and selecting `Dark (Visual Studio)` and getting the same output as the first image.