# Port Visual Studio Code Dark+ text coloring to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

I really like Visual Studio Code, but so far it lacks certain features I have in VS 2017. Yet, I'd prefer to have coloring I had in VS Code default (Dark+) theme. Any ideas how to port it to VS 2017?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code color theme in Visual Studio 2017 for JavaScript and TypeScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958306/visual-studio-code-color-theme-in-visual-studio-2017-for-javascript-and-typescri)