# Customize theme comments color

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the "rainbow" theme extension. I like colors except for comments, they are too dark to read. I want to change just the comments color. Do I have to go through this (generate a Yo Code theme from the existing rainbow theme):

[How to edit default dark theme for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165362/how-to-edit-default-dark-theme-for-visual-studio-code)

just to make this change? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I found the file C:\Users\lance-p\.vscode\extensions\gerane.Theme-rainbow-0.0.2\themes\rainbow.tmTheme and changed   <key>name</key>
            <string>Comment</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>comment</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#424c55</string>
            </dict> to #ffffff, and it changed the comment color. Although it's not white, at least its legible now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change color of comments in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with version [1.15 (July 2017)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_user-definable-syntax-highlighting-colors) you can do this in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#fff"
}
```