# How do I change the color of comments in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I went through https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference but can't seem to find the setting for changing the comment color.

I am currently using Atom One Dark Theme and just like to lighten the color a little bit so I can read it better.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

From [1.15 (July 2017)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_user-definable-syntax-highlighting-colors) you can change it from [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#d4922f"
},
```

From [1.20 (January 2018)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_theme-specific-color-customizations) you can also do it for each theme separately:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Atom One Dark]": {
        "comments": "#d4922f"
    }
},
```

Or now you can specify settings for multiple themes at once as `"[Atom One Dark][Tomorrow Night Blue]": {...}`

### Finding the right scope:

To find the right scope, you need to open up the tokens and scopes inspector. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open up the command palette, and then type and search for `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`, as shown here:

[image]

Select it. Now, you can click around on different syntax to see the syntax highlighting scope and information, like this:

[image]

When done, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the tokens and scopes inspection mode.

Selector priority:

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations#_textmate-themes

---

---

Ok, more examples (for `js`):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "INSERT_SCOPE_HERE",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#ff0000"
        }
    }]
}
```

`comment` [image]
`punctuation.definition.comment` [image]
`comment.block.documentation` [image]
`storage.type.class.jsdoc` [image]
`entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc` [image]
`variable.other.jsdoc` [image]

Comment: any possibilities for background/foreground ?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors

Comment: Anybody know what the setting is for the // and /* before the comment text? Also what the setting is for the " before strings?

Comment: You can try "finding the right scope" link from the answer.

Comment: Any way to change the color of the start and end section of a comment block. `/**` and `*/` they stay unchanged after setting the comment color. the middle section is changing color.

Comment: @Alex Hi Mate, would you please help me tweak the comments on vscode for PHP. Here is what I want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928165/vs-code-disable-php-comment-coloring?noredirect=1#comment96621251_54928165

Comment: I can't cover all the languages. There is a command in my answer that shows you all the scopes in any language => use it to find and tweak the colors. Thanks.

Comment: What about chaging color of HTML comments?

Comment: `text.html comment` ?

Comment: You need to include this option inside of the `settings.json` object that includes all of your settings, so that this computes as valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I took the github dark theme and changed the comments to this:
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "comments": "#7294a0"
  },  
Now it looks ilke the comments are just disabled active text. Feels much cleaner.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this who needs help for it in Sublime Text instead, see my notes on it [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/sublime_gcode#sublime-text-packages-and-syntax-highlighting--how-it-all-works) and [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/sublime_gcode#to-check-the-syntax-highlighting-scope-of-a-particular-place-in-a-source-code-file), in the main readme of my [sublime_gcode](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/sublime_gcode) gcode syntax highlighter repo for Sublime Text.

Answer (score 69):

1.Go to your settings.
[image]

2.Type “editor.tokenColorCustomizations” into the search bar then click on “Edit in settings.json”:
[image]

3.By default, “editor.tokenColorCustomizations” is set to “null”. To customize the comment color, you can add:

> {   "comments": "[color code]" }

You can type something like this:

```
> "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
>     "comments": "#e45e91"   },
```

4.Change the color of comments,based on your liking by hovering over the color and choosing your desired color.
[image]
5.Then save the changes.(Ctrl+S)

6.Exit the program. open it again, you will see the changes.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the visuals. Makes it much easier to navigate.

Answer (score 29):

To expand on the answer and @Johnny Derp's comment.  You can change the font color and style using:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "comment",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                "foreground": "#C69650",
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

`background` cannot be changed in this way, only the color and style.  As of June, 2018.

---

Also in answer to a couple of comments about changing comments `puntuation` (like the `//`) colors - which now have to be separately colored with their own textmate rule, a change may be coming to fix that in the October 2019 release - at this point it is an unresolved issue but added to the October 2019 milestone.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/102

Answer (score 23):

In VS Code: 1.56.2

Add to `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "comment",
                "comment.block.documentation",
                "comment.block.documentation.js",
                "comment.line.double-slash.js",
                "storage.type.class.jsdoc",
                "entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc",
                "variable.other.jsdoc",
                "punctuation.definition.comment",
                "punctuation.definition.comment.begin.documentation",
                "punctuation.definition.comment.end.documentation"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                "foreground": "#287a1d"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If there is still stuff missing: `CTRL+SHIFT+P` => `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` (see screenshots added by [@Gabriel Staples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4561887/gabriel-staples) to [the main answer by @Alex, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649255/4561887)). Hover over the parts that are not colored correctly and add them to `"scope"`.

There you are. :)

Comment: Oh my gosh, that has fixed everything for me, I didn't know this was a thing. I can FINALLY find all the colors I want to edit. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted. Before I knew about this Q&A, I wrote a tutorial about this on GitHub here: [How to customize colors in VSCode by using the built-in "Scope inspector" tool](https://github.com/volosovich/Monokai-ST3-theme-for-vscode/issues/14)

Answer (score 8):

## Doc, Block, and Line settings

To have differnet colors for Doc, Block, and Line comments (tested in C++):

[image: Comment previews]

I.e. for the `Cobalt2` theme:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Cobalt2]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "comment.block",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment.end",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment.begin"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#85b3f8",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": [
                    "comment.block.documentation",
                    "comment.block.javadoc.java",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment.begin.documentation",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment.end.documentation"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#6bddb7",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },{
                "scope":["comment.line", "punctuation.definition.comment"],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

btw: The new default theme is called `[Default Dark Modern]` and the old default was called `[Default Dark+]`. You can apply the mod to multiple themes at the same time by just putting them in the same quote. (`"[Default Dark Modern][Default Dark+]"`).

Answer (score 6):

While commenting on comment subject, I found "Better Comments" extension of VS Code very useful. You can give various colors ‎to your comments and hence categorize your comments based on importance etc. ‎
Default comments color can also be changed.‎
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments
Example:‎
[image: Borrowed from extension page]
This extension can be configured in User Settings or Workspace settings.‎

[image]

Comment: Yep, this is what I use to. Its really easy to configure, works well, and is highly customizable. If you want to color your comments, "F" all the noise above, this extension is what you want.

Comment: I like to change the background colour of comments in any code editor. Makes the comments pop way out more for me, rather than just blurring together with the code. Better Comment let me do this with making a default "tag": "", setting the "color" setting to #000000 and the background to #00A000 (Deep green).
This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: For  tag's background color what are other options other than "transparent". I gave hex color code like "#DDFF33" and it did not work?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the token colors cannot be customized within the settings at the moment:

> The most prominent editor colors are the token colors that are based
>   on the language grammar installed. These colors are defined by the
>   Color Theme and can (currently) not be customized in the settings.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference

I did notice that if you go into the theme folders, for example:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-monokai
and edit the monokai-color-theme.json file, look for the line with "name": "Comment" and change the "foreground" color it will work. Just make sure to restart the program.

Comment: Why go through the trouble. This is by far the worst way to color comments.

Answer (score 5):

Like  Mark said, but add in the `"scope":` after `"comment"`

> "punctuation.definition.comment"

to color also the punctuation,

> e.g. (`//` in javescript | `/* */` in css | `<!-- -->` in html).

```
"scope": ["comment", "punctuation.definition.comment"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your VS code by simply edit your setting file in VS code and follow these 3 steps.

**step1:**
[image]

**step2:**
[image]

**Step3:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To change VS Code comment color

File --> Preferences --> Settings

Choose the "Workspace Settings" tab to only change it for this project
Choose the "User Settings" tab to change it for all projects

Do a search for "settings.json" and look for an option to "Edit in settings.json"

Insert this color setting for the comments somewhere inside the curly brackets:

"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#ff4"
  }

It might complain that you are overriding your current color theme, just ignore that.

If there is already a section for "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" then just add the line to specify the comment color.

Answer (score 1):

Update #2 (newest): see here to go back to the old settings: [How to colorize Python docstrings to your liking; ex: like strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440715/4561887)

Update #1: I [opened a PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/182162) to just fix this in the upstream theme in the VSCode source. [Issue: Python multi-line comment strings should be treated as comments in the Monokai theme](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182163).

### How to subdue Python block comment strings in VSCode in order to look like Sublime Text's Monokai

I really like how comments in Sublime Text are subdued so they don't get in your way. So, to go from this in VSCode, where the Python block comment strings are an obnoxious yellow:

[image: image with yellow comments]

...to this, where the Python block comment strings are a nice subdued green just like line comments:

[image: image with subdued green comments]

...you need to add this to your `settings.json` file:

```json
{
    // your other settings here

    // new settings to fix the block comment strings:

    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    // For Python multi-line docstrings / block comments!
                    "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    // match regular Python comment color
                    "foreground": "#88846F"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

See here for how to open `settings.json` from the command palette, and for where it's located on your OS: [How can I open Visual Studio Code's 'settings.json' file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052/4561887)

In order to find out that I needed to use the textmate scope of `"string.quoted.docstring.multi.python"` above, I used the **tokens and scopes inspector** in VSCode, as follows:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open up the command palette, and then type and search for `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`, as shown here:

[image]

Select it. Now, you can click around on different syntax to see the syntax highlighting scope and information, like this. You can see the `"string.quoted.docstring.multi.python"` scope in the image below, when I have my cursor on the `"""` characters at the start of a Python comment string block:

[image]

When done, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the tokens and scopes inspection mode.

Use this technique to customize other scopes and colors to your liking, or to see what colors and formatting other scopes currently have if you want to copy them.

### How to subdue C and C++ Doxygen comments in VSCode in order to look like Sublime Text's Monokai

See my tutorial on GitHub here: [How to customize colors in VSCode by using the built-in "Scope inspector" tool](https://github.com/volosovich/Monokai-ST3-theme-for-vscode/issues/14)

### References

1. Official VSCode documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes
2. [The main answer by @Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649255/4561887), including re-using the images and text I wrote into Alex's answer as well by editing it.
3. [The answer by @RND](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68008322/4561887)
4. My own tutorial on GitHub: [TUTORIAL: How to customize colors and subdue the bright colors in the doxygen comments](https://github.com/volosovich/Monokai-ST3-theme-for-vscode/issues/14)
5. My own trial and error and figuring it out with the scope inspector tool because this irritated me so much.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the language support extension you're using uses TextMate grammars or semantic highlighting (see also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#tokenization).

#### For language-support extensions using TextMate-based highlighting

VS Code seems to define some generic scope names (`comment`, `comment.block`, `comment.block.documentation`, and `comment.line`), but from my observation, not every language extension (even counting only builtin extensions) adheres to this convention.

You need to figure out what TextMate scopes it defines for comments, which you can do by using the token scope inspector- use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). It will open an inspector widget that follow the cursor and show what TextMate scopes match for the token under the cursor. Once you know what tokens exist, pick whichever one(s) is the most suitable and write a corresponding rule in the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

If you want to get a quick overview of possibly relevant scope names, here's a UNIX command you could use to scan a directory for TextMate grammars and pick out scope names that contain the substring "comment" in their name: `jq '.' $(find . -name '*.tm*') | command grep '"name".*comment' | awk '{$1=$1};1' | sort | uniq`. You could run this from your VS Code installation's directory to get such scope names for the grammars of builtin extensions, or from your `.vscode/extensions/` directory in your user home directory to scan for scopes from grammars of non-builtin extensions that you manually installed. Then you could do a pass to check each of those out and see if it's something you want to modify.

Then you would write something like this in your settings.json file:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[name of your current colour theme here]": { // optionally remove this colour theme wrapper to apply the customization for all themes
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "commentscope1, commentscope2, commentscope3, ...",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#ff0000", // TODO
            },
        }],
    },
},
```

#### For language-support extensions using Semantic highlighting

For language support extensions that instead use semantic highlighting, it's much simpler. Instead of the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting, use the `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` setting, and write a rule for the `comment` token type (one of [the standard token types](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#standard-token-types-and-modifiers)). Ex.

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[name of your current colour theme here]": { // optionally remove this colour theme wrapper to apply the customization for all themes
        "rules": {
            "comment": "#ff0000", // TODO
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

i use

[Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) extension for vscode and i believe that is the best option

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use the dark theme of this extension, it is inherited from Material Theme but has more useful syntax aspects [Arcaelas Insiders | Themes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcaelas-insiders.arcaelas-insiders-themes&ssr=false#review%20-details)