# Visual Studio Code One Dark Pro Theme Commnent color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, themes, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with One Dark Pro Theme (here is the link):

[VSCode One Dark Pro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhuangtongfa.Material-theme)

I would like to change a color of "Comment Line". Now it's really faded gray color, which makes it hard to read. I would like to have something more greenish - like in classic VIsual Studio green comment color.

I've tried almost everything, but nothing works.

Thank you and best regards
Jiri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change color of comments in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 1.15 July 2017 you will be able to customize theme's token colors in `setting.json` like that:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#33ff33"
}
```

Screenshot from insider version (1.15.0)

[image]

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_15.md#user-definable-syntax-highlighting-colors