# How to add color to a specific word in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working with C++, I want `string` keyword to have the same color as every other C++ keyword in the theme which is `#c678dd`.

Is it possible to modify it in the settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148857/customizing-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code One Dark Pro Theme Commnent color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577438/visual-studio-code-one-dark-pro-theme-commnent-color)

Comment: Do you get any scope when you CTRL-Shift-P?  If you do, you could modify that tokenColorCustomization.  If you get no scope, try something like "TODO Highlight" extension to highlight any work you choose.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of other questions. To accomplish this requires a custom syntax token, which is not addressed by highlighting.