# Can't change theme color in Visual Studio Code: "Unknown configuration settings"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't change the colour of 'comments' in Visual Studio Code. I'm following the instructions in this post: [Visual Studio Code One Dark Pro Theme Commnent color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577438/visual-studio-code-one-dark-pro-theme-commnent-color) but it doesn't work. VSC is outputting an error ("Unknown configuration setting"). The current theme colour is "Zenburn (No Bold)"

My code is:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Zenburn (No Bold)",
"editor.fontSize": 16,
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-great-icons",
"[Zenburn (No Bold)]": {
    "comments": "#fff"
}
}
```

Comment: Your Zenburn setting has to be inside the tokenColorCustomizations object.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: OK, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark !! Now the code works:
    {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Zenburn (No Bold)",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-great-icons",
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Zenburn (No Bold)]": {
        "comments": "#c8ce94"
    }
    },
    }