# How to modify the theme in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is not a duplicate of how to configure theme options, that is clear from answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649255/220949).

I'd like to *modify* or *tweak* the current setting, meaning: I'd like to load what is currently configured. For example the value currently configured for 
`editor.tokenColorCustomizations["[Cobalt2]"]["comments"]["foreground"]` 
to be able to tweak it a bit, say making the color more bright.

When I load this key in the `User Settings` I see a color red (`"#FF0000`) as default, which is obviously not what the theme has.

I know I can 1) open the `cobalt2.json` 2) find the setting and 3) copy/paste in my User Settings. But I was looking for a more friendly/easier approach.

Is there a more friendly/easier approach? How can I preload the current setting in my User Settings?

Comment: User settings just override anything in your theme and those just override anything in the default.

Comment: I gave up trying to find the defaults, and just used the digital color meter to measure the colors on macOS

Answer (score 16):

You can use this command from command palette:

```
Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings
```

to see all the colors defined. If you have overwritten some colors in `settings.json` that change will be reflected too.

Command to assign to a keybinding: `workbench.action.generateColorTheme`.

Also, there is an open issue to fill the current value in settings: [#25633](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25633)

Comment: once generated, how can I save it as a new theme?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme

Comment: the colors that are commented get the default colors, which are defined elswhere, I believe -- how can we see those values?