# Change color of characters surrounding comments in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

how can I change the color of the characters that come before and after a comment in vs code. Im Talking about  or /* */ or # characters. 
I know how to change the comment color

[How do I change color of comments in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code)

but couldn’t find anything regarding the „framing“ characters.

Comment: I don't believe this is achievable. Why is this necessary?

Comment: I just want don’t like it with different colors. Why shouldn’t it be achievable. There must be a setting to do this like some scope settings. I just don’t know where to look...

Comment: That's a pretty specific request and not really a feature that many people would even care about. I'd be surprised if something like this exists.

Comment: @emsimpson92 I don’t know what such a comment is aiming at. We ask questions here to seek a solution it’s not for you to judge if that is seemly or not, if you don’t know the answer, just stay calm but pls refrain from trolling...

Comment: I wasn't trolling. I just said I'd be surprised if it exists.

Comment: ok, then sorry for my misinterpretation; as you see it fortunatly does, I'm already diving into the whole `textMateRules`thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this rather simply.  Use "`Inspect TM Scopes`" in the command palette to inspect those characters.   It will give a different scope for each language, something like :

```
punctuation.definition.comment.js
```

for javascript comments.  Now you can use that in your user settings like so:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [

      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.comment.js",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#f00",
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

You will obviously have a different but similar scope for other languages.

---

And see the short answer added to [How to change VisualStudioCode comment color with it's slashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728774/how-to-change-visualstudiocode-comment-color-with-its-slashes/58424297#58424297) about **possible** plans to **fix this** in the October, 2019 release.  So the punctuation would not have to be independently colored.  [It is now fixed in the Insider's Build.]

Comment: great, thanks a lot, worked like a charm, you can simply add the ending of the language you need to apply it to other languages' comments...

```"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Monokai Classic]": {
            "comments": "#60d01a",
            "strings": "#ece233",
            "selector": "#60d01a"
            },
        "textMateRules": [

            {
                "scope": "punctuation.definition.comment.yaml",
                "settings": {
                "foreground": "#60d01a",
                }
            }
            ]
```

Comment: do you know, how one could set this up for multiple languages, does the command support lists/arrays?

Comment: never mind, I found it out, the only one that doesn't seem to work is the extension `css`, any idea, what the proper extension here for css could be?

Comment: I see these scopes for css comments using the above method: punctuation.definition.comment.end.css and punctuation.definition.comment.begin.css

Comment: You do NOT have to specifically define each language. You can leave off the language extension from the scope like so: `"scope": "punctuation.definition.comment",`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to fully define the comment colors globally. You do not have to do one for each language!

**settings.json**

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#636363",
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.comment",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#636363",
        }
    }]
},
```

Notice I omitted the language, ie: `.php`, from the end of the `scope` line.

This will do both the beginning/end of the comment block, and the comment itself. I was baffled when I changed my comment colors and the `/**` and `*/` where not changed. This solved it and made the comments all one color.