# How to change VisualStudioCode comment color with it's slashes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I added this code to my setting.json

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#00ff00"
}
```

But It doesn't change the color for slashes as you can see the below screenshot.
It remains still grayed.

How can I change the whole comment color contains slashes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the comment punctuation colorCustomization may be corrected - that is, the `punctuation` like `//` may be included in the `comment` scope in the October 2018 release.  It is an open issue but was added to the October 2019 milestone, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/102.

So that the comment punctuation would no longer need to be separately colored.

It is fixed in the Insider's Build as of October 25, 2019 so that

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#00ff00"
}
```

will color the comment body and punctuation/marker as well.

Answer (score 2):

The comments definition (// or # for other languages) can be customized with the `punctuation.definition.comment` scope in the `textMateRules` array.

Example:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Material Theme Darker High Contrast]": { // optional name of a specific theme
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.comment",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#00ff00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see the scopes of all the command `Inspect TM Scopes` in the command palette.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this same answer in several places, but for whatever reason, it just wasn't working for me with any of the `Material Theme *` themes. No matter what I did, the `//` in JS and first `#` in Ruby/Shell wouldn't change colors.

[image]

To get around this, I had to use the `Community` version of the `Material Theme *` themes: e.g. `"workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme Darker High Contrast"`.

[image: Screenshot with fix]

Hope this is helpful for anyone else encountering this issue!

Comment: Agreed, there is definitely something in the non-community Matherial Theme (v4.16.0) which overrides these scopes. Only language specific scope worked (ie. punctuation.definition.comment.sql) to specify the color of comment opening/closure. Switching to Community edition works perfectly with generic scopes for comments. Thanks.