# How to change the color of "comment definition characters" in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit.

I currently am overriding some settings for a theme I like, but noticed that the comma color I chose does not change the # from the theme as well:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Darker High Contrast",
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Material Theme Darker High Contrast]": {
            "comments": "#229977"
            "types": "#f64343"
        }
    },
}
```

How could I change the # to be the same color as I set the comments itself?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728774/how-to-change-visualstudiocode-comment-color-with-its-slashes - this has been fixed in the Insider's Build as of this date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question the "comment definition" characters is in the theme "grey" and with your settings the comment text is now green.

To also color the "comment definition" characters add these to your settings

```
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Darker High Contrast",
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "[Material Theme Darker High Contrast]": {
        "comments": "#229977",
        "textMateRules": [
          { "scope":"punctuation.definition.comment",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#229977"}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

This is valid for JSON files and Python.

For which file type do you need the customisation? The rule names vary.