# How can I change the font-weight, size and color of only comments in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've only been able to change the color of the comments in the following way but couldn't change the weight or the font.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Monokai][Atom One Dark]": {
            "comments": "#5a8738"
        },
    },
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424297/836330 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728774/how-to-change-visualstudiocode-comment-color-with-its-slashes to see how to change font-weight and color for comments.  I don't believe you can change the font-size though.