# VS Code Disable PHP Comment Coloring

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to disable the colors in the comments (on PHP at least, it would be great if it's disabled on every language) and make them all blue.
Here is a picture of colored comments.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change color of comments in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @jwismar it doesn't cover PHP.

Comment: I suppose you refer to disabling annotation support in syntax highlighting. I can be easily wrong but I suspect there's no way unless you want to fiddle with the grammar definition file. The PHP one seems to be ported from Atom editor. You can find yours at `\resources\app\extensions\php\syntaxes\php.tmLanguage.json` inside installation directory (but please don't edit it in place).