# How do I change the colour of the results grid borders in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

There must be a way to do this, because switching between different themes changes the colour of the borders in the results grid. But I want to customise it for one of themes I'm currently using. (Which I know is possible based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code).)

The only reference I can find in Microsoft's documentation is this page for Visual Studio Code:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

...but seeing as the results grid is an Azure Data Studio feature, there's nothing in there talking about it.

Anyone have any thoughts??