# How can I change syntax color tags used in HTML on My Theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My current theme is One Dark Pro. Overall, I like this theme but there are some syntax colors that I really don't like, such as HTML syntax colors. I really like the ones which are in Ayu theme Mirage. So, I want to edit these colors and it's been 2 days and I am stuck with this problem. I tried everything like read the VS-code docs, watch videos and read a lot of articles but can't change them. Although, I was able to change comments colors because of this article([How do I change color of comments in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code)).Also, I thought about just switching to ayu theme mirage but it does not have diverse colors while coding in JavaScript.
I will attach some screen-shots please help me out guys.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCFK5.png

Comment: use the same trick for some other TextMate scope

Comment: Could please elaborate it for me coz..... I tried it too but failed.