# Incorrect vscode theme color

Tags: visual-studio-code

My vscode theme color has been behaving abnormally and I just noticed this issue today.

As shown in the image below, regardless of whether it's the `dark+` or `dark modern` theme, my **python docstrings** are displayed in **green** instead of the expected **orange** color.
(The docstring should be orange in python)

[image]

I can't figure out the reason behind this issue and I'm unsure how to resolve it.

Here is my `setting.json` file.

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "glassit.alpha": 255,
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.foreground":"#EEFFFF",
        "terminalCursor.background":"#EEFFFF",
        "terminalCursor.foreground":"#EEFFFF",
        "terminal.ansiBlack":"#212121",
        "terminal.ansiBlue":"#82AAFF",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#4A4A4A",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#d698c1",
        "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#89DDFF",
        "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#C3E88D",
        "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#C792EA",
        "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#F07178",
        "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#FFFFFF",
        "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#FFCB6B",
        "terminal.ansiCyan":"#89DDFF",
        "terminal.ansiGreen":"#C3E88D",
        "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#C792EA",
        "terminal.ansiRed":"#F07178",
        "terminal.ansiWhite":"#EEFFFF",
        "terminal.ansiYellow":"#FFCB6B"
    },
    
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "markdown-preview-enhanced.previewTheme": "github-dark.css",
    "markdown-preview-enhanced.codeBlockTheme": "atom-dark.css",
    "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
    "pasteImage.path": "${currentFileDir}/img/",
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "Default Dark+",

    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
}
```

Additional information: I previously had the **[vibrancy extensions](https://github.com/illixion/vscode-vibrancy-continued)** installed, but I have since removed it and used the fix **check**. I'm not sure if this extension is causing the error today.

Since the cause of the error is unknown, the information I can provide is limited. If you need specific information, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In VS Code 1.79, Python docstrings are colored like comments. How do I return it to the string color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436694/in-vs-code-1-79-python-docstrings-are-colored-like-comments-how-do-i-return-it) Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76466400/why-are-docstrings-and-block-comments-suddenly-the-same-color-as-a-single-line-c

Comment: In short, someone made a change to the source code of VSCode, it was approved and merged in, and much of the community hates it.  I think an upcoming release reverts it (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/184938)

Comment: Thanks, It turned out to be a revised version of vscode, indeed this PR is a bit unbelievable