# How do I customise the color of HTML tags in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the Abyss theme which I like, but certain colors are too dark. I have customized some token colors using (for instance):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Abyss]": {
        "keywords": "#7ea4df",
```

but I can't figure out how to change the color of HTML tags in the editor. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can go into the theme's .json file and modify it to suit your needs, as [mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353341/9374673). Mine was located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-abyss\themes`

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments by @www-0av-Com, the path to the file is now `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-abyss\themes`, where `<username>` is your Windows user.

You can use `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open the Command Palette and then open up the [Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations#_new-textmate-scope-inspector-widget) to look at the TextMate scope of the element you're interested in modifying. In the case of the HTML tag in the abyss theme it's `entity.name.tag`. You can see what the Scope Inspector looks like in the second image below.

Then go into the abyss-color-theme.json file and search for that string and modify the color of the tags as you see fit. I changed mine to an ugly orange color as below:

[image: Modifying the theme source]

[image: Modified HTML tag coloring]

Comment: Thanks! See my alternative approach below, based on your info, in case you'd prefer to avoid editing the theme itself.

Comment: The path is now "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-abyss\themes" assuming \user\ is your PC's user name. Also, I believe @"see sharper" 's answer is much better.

Comment: @www-0av-Com Thanks for the heads up! I've edited my answer with the new path to the file.

Comment: My pleasure. May I add that whilst "see sharper" 's answer is better, yours adds some valuable, even essential insights. For example, who would guess the attribute colouration would be "entity.other.attribute-name" unless they found and reviewed that file? VSCode needs autocomplete on it's own config files! _Please thank with upvote on comment.. that helps my profile._ Cheers

Comment: This changes the tag name color. But how do we change color of '<' and '>' just for tags?

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer is good, but thought I'd add this as it obviates the need to edit the theme JSON itself. I edited my settings as follows:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Abyss]": {
        "keywords": "#7ea4df",
        "types": "#1fa8d8",
        "comments": "#727272",
        "strings": "#29a792",
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.tag",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#7ea4df"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: Good answer. I was wondering if there was a way to edit it in the user settings instead, but the VSCode documentation omits the `"textMateRules"` key, and so I was lost trying to find the right way to make the modification.

Comment: ...and if you like, to save your user settings as a new theme: "Generate a theme file using the Developer: Generate Color Theme from Current Settings command from the Command Palette" - from this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#syntax-colors

Comment: I am fairly new with creating VSCode extensions. I am creating a syntax highlighting extension and was wondering in which file and folder would I add the mentioned code? I only want to change some colors in my syntax highlighting for my custom extension and not the entire theme.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's might be too late, but for anyone who doesn't want to make this manually, there is the [Rainbow Tags extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=voldemortensen.rainbow-tags).

I'm using it for a couple of weeks and it's very satisfying.

Comment: If it's useful, never it's too late, my friend.

Answer (score 3):

For mac users, you can follow the below steps

1. Open finder
2. Press cmd+shift+h to  open users folder
3. Go to  users/your user name
4. Press cmd+shift+. To open hidden files
5. Go to .vscode/extensions/sdras.night-owl /themes/Night owl-color-theme.json(In my case its night owl theme.)
6. Drag and Open the file in vscode
7. Open the html file you want to customise
8. Select the div  element  and press cmd+shift+p
9. Select developer: inspector editor token and scopes
10. Select the textmatescope eg: entity.name.tag.js

    [image]

11. Now open settings.json file in vscode
12. Add below code

    ```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

        "[Night Owl (No Italics)]": {

            "textMateRules": [
            {

                "scope": "entity.name.tag.js",

                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#7fdbca"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#82AAFF",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
    ```

change the foreground to whatever you want to use.
and your done.