# VS Code - How do I customize the theme colors of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using the VS Code theme Base 16 Twilight.

This is about the best theme that I have found, but I can't seem to find a way to edit the color that controls this chunk of code.

I would like to make the highlighted bit here in orange. How do I go about doing that?

[image]

Here is the information from the TM Scope inspector. It says "No theme selector".
[image]

Comment: Use command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope` and read up on theme customization

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, I agree with you in most cases, but in here he/she wants to show the coloring of the code, and not the code itself, so I think it is valid

Comment: @CarlosGarcia - i see your point ... but think the text would be more useful. perhaps both would make sense? plus, the `-Properties` that is hilited should NOT be ... it is a parameter name, not a parameter value.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey as far as I understand the question, the text is completely irrelevant. the question is "How can I color parameter values differently than parameter names?"... the title also says it clear, How can he customize the color of PowerShell cmdlets... Note: This is how I see it, I might be wrong :)

Comment: Hi all - sorry for the confusing question. I have added some additional information to my original post, with another screenshot. The TM Scope inspector states "No theme selector". Does this mean this bit can not be customized?

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a PowerShell or VSCode issue, which is what we are here for. As this is a question about how do I configure VScode for X or Y.

So, this is really off-topic for StackOverflow and should be moved to SuperUser or StackExchange

Yet, you can always, create your own theme to use or crack open the theme file you are using and change it, if the author made to source code available of course, or use your settings (json files), PSReadline settings, etc... this is documented in the VSCode help files on the MS docs site.

> Changing the Color Theme
>
> https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/themes

[How to edit default dark theme for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165362/how-to-edit-default-dark-theme-for-visual-studio-code)

> With new versions of VSCode you don't need to hunt for the settings
>   file to customize the theme. Now you can customize your color theme
>   with the workbench.colorCustomizations and
>   editor.tokenColorCustomizations user settings. 
>   Documentation on the matter can be found [here.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)