# How can I find the folder of the theme I'm using in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to customize the theme I'm using, how can I find the folder of it?

I wanted to customize 'Atom One Darker' theme  but I can't find its folder in `app/extensions`.

How can I find it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165362/how-to-edit-default-dark-theme-for-visual-studio-code

Comment: I can find the default theme, but I wanted to customize a non-default theme that I can't find the folder of.

Comment: On Windows 10, on my system, the built-in themes are located in: C:\Users\Ross\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_where-are-extensions-installed) explains, depending on your platform, the extensions are located the following folder:

- **Windows** `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- **macOS** `~/.vscode/extensions`
- **Linux** `~/.vscode/extensions`

Each extension (the themes are extensions too) is stored here in a directory whose name is generated by the concatenation of its ID and the installed version.

Search for a directory whose name starts with `christopherafbjur.vscode-theme-onedarker-` (it ends with the extension version).

---

To find the ID of an extension, open the Extensions view (menu -> View -> Open View... -> Extensions), filter the installed extensions (use the menu that pops up from the funnel icon or type `@installed` in the "Search extensions" box), find the one you need then right click on it and choose "Copy Extension Id" from the popup menu.

Comment: This only appears to be true for third-party themes you've installed. You can browse the default themes at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/theme-defaults/themes and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions (I don't know why they're in two locations).

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, you can find the default theme configuration files in C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes

Make sure you're in the Programs folder and not the .vscode folder that's in Documents

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to customize a non-default themethat I couldn't find in extensions folder.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct, it is incomplete (where is located the `AppData` folder where the path starts?) and it does not mention anything about the OS. It works only on Windows. What about macOS and Linux? At least you should mention that the answer applies only to Windows. (It does not help too much on other OSes).